# Extract data corresponding to an ID in excel (VBA - Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having 2 excel files, one big file contains all data, and the second one is smaller and filter manually. They can be like this:

BIG EXCEL FILE

```
ID ------- Infor

123------ABC

134------BCD
```

SMALL EXCEL FILE

```
ID-------Infor

123------...

333-----...
```

So if I want to fill in the small excel file, I have to copy the ID, paste into the big file, copy the data of that ID, then paste into the small file.

Can you help me to develop a VBA that can automaticallly find same ID and paste data next to it?? I suppose that we can merge 2 file excels together for easier implementation.

Comment: We can *help* you, but typically here you're expected to describe what you already tried, along with any specific problems you ran into.  Please review [ask] and consider updating your question.

Comment: Have you tried to use the excel formula `vlookup`. It is easy possible to combine two dataset also in different files. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Converting this result back to static text can be done by recording a macro, while copy and insert as value.